# How can i get a j-pop j-rock tone in Guitar Rig

Tags: electric-guitar, rock-n-roll

I'm new to the electric guitar. I wanted to know how can I reproduce the same tone/sound as in the anime openings? Here are some examples:

- 
- 

I really appreciate your help. Thank you :))

Comment: I don't have any specifics, but those could be done with any high-gain amp & probably a compressor on the input. Welcome back to the 80's ;)

Comment: I'll take that into consideration. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a high-gain amp simulation such as the "Lead 800" or "Rectifier" and a closed-back 4x12 cabinet simulation. Use a moderate amount of "Metal Distortion" or "Crunch Distortion." Add a short to medium length delay with a moderate to high feedback setting and some reverb. On the EQ, boost the mid-range frequencies (500-700 Hz). Set the compressor with a moderate attack and release setting with a low ratio.

And spend a lot of trial-and-error trying to match the tones you want. Welcome to sound design!